# lambdified sympy expression returns incorrect result

Tags: python, floating-point, sympy, numerical-methods, lambdify

I encountered following problem, first I will explain briefly what is going on:

```
f(x)
g(x, y) = f(x) - y
```

From there we expect

```
g(x, f(x)) = f(x) - f(x) = 0
```

`lambdified g(x,y)` returns something very close to zero instead of zero. Here's a code that reproduces the problem. It arrives only when I put sufficient amount of `log` evaluations in `f(x)`

gist: https://gist.github.com/marekyggdrasil/39a24213ebaba6293464d116821cc334

source:

```
from sympy import Symbol, pprint, log, lambdify

# setting symbols
g1 = Symbol("gamma1")
g2 = Symbol("gamma2")
g3 = Symbol("gamma3")
g4 = Symbol("gamma4")
rt = Symbol("rt")

# setting expressions
criteria  = (g1 * log(g1, 2.0))/2.0
criteria += (g2 * log(g2, 2.0))/2.0
criteria += (g3 * log(g3, 2.0))/2.0
criteria += (g4 * log(g4, 2.0))/2.0
rooteq = criteria - rt

print "\ncriteria function: "
pprint(criteria)

print "\ncriteria function - rt: "
pprint(rooteq)

# lambdifying expressions to callable functions
tsymbols = [g1, g2, g3, g4, rt]
lambfun_criteria = lambdify(tsymbols, criteria)
lambfun_rooteq = lambdify(tsymbols, rooteq)

# example point x
x = [0.25006462253641376, 2.2501938662000542, 2.2501938662000542, 2.2501938662000542, 0.0]

# evaluating of criteria on x
rootval = lambfun_criteria(*x)

# setting rt to this evaluation
x[4] = rootval

print "\nactual evaluation of rooteq: " + str(lambfun_rooteq(*x))
print "\nexpected evaluation of rooteq: " + str(- x[4] + lambfun_criteria(*x))
```

output

```
$ python lambdifytest.py 

criteria function: 
0.721347520444482⋅γ₁⋅log(γ₁) + 0.721347520444482⋅γ₂⋅log(γ₂) + 0.721347520444482⋅γ₃⋅log(γ₃) + 0.721347520444482⋅γ₄⋅log(γ₄)

criteria function - rt: 
0.721347520444482⋅γ₁⋅log(γ₁) + 0.721347520444482⋅γ₂⋅log(γ₂) + 0.721347520444482⋅γ₃⋅log(γ₃) + 0.721347520444482⋅γ₄⋅log(γ₄) - rt

actual evaluation of rooteq: 4.4408920985e-16

expected evaluation of rooteq: 0.0
```

Comment: Hello, looks like it's a [floating point representation error](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error), basically, because you perform operations on floating points, you accumulate approximation errors that don't add up to 0
if you just execute `0.4+0.3+0.2`, you'll get `0.8999999999999999` in python

Comment: I don't think it is that, argument against it would be that it is not accumulating, there is only one evaluation on the way, maybe I should pose a question differently: why last and before last lines of source deliver different results?

Comment: As you can see `lambfun_rooteq(*x)` and `- x[4] + lambfun_criteria(*x)` are exactly same computations on exactly same values, yet yield different results, I think that is the key problem.

Comment: The equation you expect to hold does not hold for floating-point arithmetic. The result can be influenced by how you (or lambdify, whatever it is)  order the operations, or how the compiler allocates registers for intermediate results. You can't both use floating point and expect exact results except in the most trivial of cases.

Comment: Lambdify is a tool provided by sympy that compiles symbolic expression into callable function.
Both expressions are identical with the same order (I checked by exporting lambda function to string) and are evaluated using identical input. I don't yet see any explanation on why the result should be different, yet it is.

Comment: Go read up on floating-point then, because this is entirely normal and expected behavior.

Comment: No it is not, it is not caused by floating point arithmetic because in this case it should still hold.
Problem is most likely caused by mixing two distinct way of handling floats, that is why there is lambdify tag in the question, I am expecting someone who knows SymPy and can advise what is best way to evaluate to obtain same result. What you guys give me with all respect, is not precise enough and certainly not useful neither for me, neither for people learning SymPy who find this question.

Comment: Actually, when I try to replicate your output, I get exactly 0.0. I ran exactly the code you posted, though it was through IPython. Dunno what the difference might be coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a custom math module can be specified when `SymPy` expression is lambdified. In my case `mpmath` helped.

Import `mpmath` and set the precision to something you find sufficient

```
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 15
```

Tell SymPy you want your lambda function to use `mpmath` for handling floating point arithmetic

```
lambfun_criteria = lambdify(tsymbols, criteria, "mpmath")
lambfun_rooteq = lambdify(tsymbols, rooteq, "mpmath")
```

Then finally I get the output

```
actual evaluation of rooteq: 0.0
expected evaluation of rooteq: 0.0
```

The cause of the issue was the following, the default floating point arithmetic used in created lambda function was not same as one used in the script that compares the results.

I updated the gist with full solution file if someone needs copy-paste

https://gist.github.com/marekyggdrasil/39a24213ebaba6293464d116821cc334#file-lambdify_test_solution-py

Edit: forgot to give docs reference

http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html

Comment: If you want to use arbitrary precision arithmetic, you might as well just stay in SymPy and use `expr.evalf(precision)`, which is a wrapper around mpmath (but returns a SymPy expression).